# Am I missing GPIOs?

Tags: gpio

I'm currently trying to resolve an issue, where my `OnOffShim` doesn't shut down the Pi 3B anymore.

So I checked `/sys/class/gpio` and was a little surprised that I don't find all GPIOs there:

```
user@rpi:~ $ ls -l /sys/class/gpio
insgesamt 0
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Jan 13 22:18 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio13 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio16 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio19 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio20 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio21 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio21
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:19 gpio26 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpiochip0/gpio/gpio26
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:18 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Jan 13 22:18 gpiochip504 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/soc:firmware/soc:firmware:expgpio/gpio/gpiochip504
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Jan 13 22:18 unexport
```

I'm especially missing the `GPIO4` and `GPIO17`, which are supposed to work with `OnOffShim`.

So is this as it should be or are there really some GPIO entries missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should control this with wiringPi instead of ?

```
sudo apt-get install wiringPi
gpio readall
```

Comment: Thanks that helped to find out it was not related to SW. A cable was broken.

Answer (score 2):

Only GPIO the sysfs has been asked to control will be listed  in `/sys/class/gpio`.

The GPIO not mentioned (i.e. other GPIO in the range 0-27) are not being controlled by sysfs.

Without knowing details of the operation of the `OnOffShim` we can't say if the absence of GPIO 4/17 is significant or not.